# unstable image transfer

Tags: python, image, sockets, tcp

I am now trying to send camera captured images from my place to another server at another remote city.
And the the server at remote city will send the received images back and I will display the images locally.
I am using python tcp socket. I display two camera captured images. One go through local area network, one go through the remote server. The local one works fine. The problem is the image get from the remote place some times displayed very slow and then suddenly gets faster and have the same speed with the local images.
I measured the performance, I can capture 30 images persecond, and it is able to sends 30 images/s in local area, but when go through the remote part, sometime it sends 20 images, some time 40.... and some time 30.
Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Please include the code. Otherwise we do not know how to help.

Comment: sender: size = len(image)
        sock.send(struct.pack('I', socket.htonl(size)))
        sock.sendall(image)

Comment: receiver: data = conn.recv(4, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
          str = struct.unpack("I", data)
          size = socket.ntohl(str[0])
          data = conn.recv(size, socket.MSG_WAITALL)

Comment: I capture 30 images every second, and the sender some times sends 30, but some times just send 10 to 20 and then sends 40 - 50 images.

Comment: My guess is the network's bandwidth is variable and I don't see anything wrong with it. One solution would be to scale down to 20 or 10 images per sec.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are transferring live video I suppose you can afford to loose a frame or two. If yes, then I suggest you try transferring video frames using UDP protocol. TCP indeed guarantees delivery but sometimes at a cost of longer times for data delivery.

Here's some [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Protocol_issues) about protocols that can be used to transfer live images from camera

Comment: yes, that's a good way to do it.
But, a problem for me is I am at a local area network, if I am using UDP, the incoming msg will go to a main machine at our LAN. and I need to establish a server to receive and transfer the image to the local machine.
That's why I am using TCP, because TCP create a individual channel between each machine, then I do not need to build the server.
But tcp not work well now, it is a good way to try using UDP.